# Matlab figure size formatting for Word

Tags: matlab, fonts, ms-word, format, figure

I'm trying to create MATLAB figures to put into a paper. The paper has very specific sizing instructions for figures that I'm having trouble matching in MATLAB. The figures need to be no greater than 3.5" width, >300 DPI, with 8pt font.

In my code, I use the following to try to set the parameters:

```
set(gcf,'PaperUnits','inches');
set(gcf,'PaperPosition',[0 0 3.5 3.5]);
xlabel('x-axis label','FontSize',8);ylabel('y-axis label','FontSize',8);
set(gca,'FontSize',8);
print('-djpeg','-r300','filename.jpg')
```

This should be giving me a 300 DPI, 3.5"x3.5" JPEG image with an 8pt font size. However, when I import the image into Word, it becomes 6.5" x 6.5" and the font size is larger than Word's 8pt font. Even if I resize the image, the font size is still too large, though it should maintain the same DPI. Are the FontSize and PaperPosition parameters not working as I expect they should or is Word doing something strange for importing?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer to your question - but why use JPG? You can export e.g. as EPS, so you still have beautiful vector graphics.

Comment: @hbaderts Recent verisons of word really don't handle EPS files well. At the very least you could go with a lossless raster format like a PNG.

Comment: I've relatively arbitrarily chose JPEG. I've heard for PNG that it can sometimes have issues when converted to PDF. I could probably try EPS as it's an acceptable image format.

Comment: Chances are if you're submitting this to a journal, they're going to want the images as separate files anyhow so they likely won't care what you insert into Word

Answer (score 1):

The font size issue was caused due to differing fonts used in MATLAB and Word. Once I learned about `set(gca,'FontName')`, the font size seemed to be correct when the image was manually resized to 3.5" x 3.5".

The image size issue seemed to be related to saving it as a JPEG. Once I swapped to PNG, the image was the correct size by default. Looking into the JPEG properties, it had the correct number of pixels for a DPI of 300 at 3.5", the sole issue was that it would have to be manually resized. Thanks for the comments that led me to finding a solution.